# Deleting elements from vector inside unordered_map

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, unordered-map

In my class, I have an unordered map of vectors, like this:

```
std::unordered_map<State, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const City>>> citiesByState;
```

My class also has these two methods:

```
  void addCity(State state, const std::shared_ptr<const City>& city);
  void removeCity(State state, const std::shared_ptr<const City>& city);
```

I add a city, like this:

```
void Manager::addCity(State state, const std::shared_ptr<const City>& city) {
  auto location = citiesByState.find(state); // Find the state in the map
  if (location == citiesByState.end()) { // If the state isn't in the map
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<const City>> cities; // Create a vector
    cities.push_back(city); // Add the city
    citiesByState[state] = cities; // Add the state and city vector to my map
  } else {
    auto vector = location->second; // Get the city vector. If the city isn't there already, add it.
    if (std::find(vector.begin(), vector.end(), city) == vector.end()) {
      vector.push_back(city);
    }
  }
}
```

Now here's my code to remove a city:

```
void Manager::removeCity(State state, const std::shared_ptr<const City>& city) {
  auto location = citiesByState.find(state);
  if (location != citiesByState.end()) {
    auto vector = location->second;
    if (vector.size() > 0) {
      std::cout << "Vector isn't empty." << std::endl;
    }
    vector.clear(); // Just empty it out for now.
  }
}
```

Then I run it like this:

```
  City city = ... // get city
  manager->addCity(State::NewYork, city);
  manager->removeCity(State::NewYork, city);
```

I can call `manager->removeCity(State::NewYork, city)` repeatedly, and each time, I see the vector is not empty. It seems like I can't remove from the Vector.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your trying to access an value in the unordered map using a type of `const std::shared_ptr<const City>&` where the map's key type is `State` in the line `citiesByState.find(city)`. Perhaps what you want is `citiesByState.find(state)`?

Comment: @D-RAJ that was a typo. I am finding it by state and still have the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

You are removing elements from a copy of the vector, not from the `std::vector` that exists in the found `location` of the `std::unordered_map`.

**Long story**

When you call `auto vector = location->second;` in `Manager::removeCity` you're making a copy of that vector inside the scope of the `if` statement. Therefore, your changes won't be reflected in the container you're targeting. Only your copy will be affected, and that too goes out of scope by the end of the `if` statement, so everything that happens if you found a `location` will not be saved in the state of the `std::unordered_map` container.

You could fix this by just calling `location->second.clear()` directly or, if you really want to give it another name, use a reference, e.g. `auto& vec = location->second; vec.clear();`. Note that this also applies for the `Manager::addCity` method.

P.S. I would stay away from using variable names that are the same as those of containers or well-established classes in the STL in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: That was exactly the issue. So trivial yet so easily missed. Thank you sir!